# SELECT Column Value based on Subselect if record exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, left-join

I have the following tables defined.

[image]

If the reader has a favorite book, a record will exist in the ReaderFavorites table for that reader/book pair.

I want to create a View that returns the following dataset when filtered by ReaderId

```
Book.Id
Book.Title
Book.Author
IsFavorite ( a bit field, true if a record exists, false otherwise)
```

View would be invoked like this:

```
    SELECT * FROM BookView WHERE ReaderId = [somevalue]
```

I can't seem to find how to create such a query.

Comment: Hint `case when exists`

Comment: Have you done some research???  There must be tons of example on the web.

Comment: This question doesn't show any research attempt whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LEFT JOIN and a conditional assignment:

```
SELECT 
    b.Id,
    b.Title,
    b.Author,
    CAST(IIF(rf.bookid IS NULL, 0, 1) as BIT) IsFavorite
FROM
    book b
    LEFT JOIN ReaderFavorites rf
        ON rf.BookId = b.Id
        AND rf.AuthorId = @AuthorId
```